# QLabel as popup: Doesn't close when clicking outside

Tags: qt

I'm using a QLabel as a popup to display HTML information when a cell is clicked in a QTableView.  The following function is called with the row name and desired popup location when the table is clicked:

```
void DatabaseTableModel::showPopup (int rowIndex, const QPoint &location) const
{
    QLabel *popup = new QLabel(data_[rowIndex].displayHtml(), 0, Qt::Popup);
    popup->setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);
    popup->setOpenExternalLinks(true);
    popup->move(location);
    popup->show();
}
```

The popup is displayed correctly at the right spot, and the HTML looks fine.  On Mac with Qt 5.6, the popup closes fine when clicked outside the popup.

However, on Windows (using Qt 5.7), the popup doesn't close on a click, either inside or outside the popup.  Any ideas on a fix?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen any other answers to the question, but I found an answer on my own:
It seems that generic widget pop-ups have been obsoleted (in practice), but using it on a QDialog works OK.  Here is the revised code:

```
void DatabaseTableModel::showPopup (int rowIndex, const QPoint &location) const {
    QDialog *popup = new QDialog(0, Qt::Popup | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    QLabel *popupLabel = new QLabel(data_.value(rowIndex).displayHtml(), 0);
    layout->addWidget(popupLabel);
    popupLabel->setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);
    popupLabel->setOpenExternalLinks(true);
    popup->setLayout(layout);
    popup->move(location);
    popup->exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [QTooltip::showText](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtooltip.html#showText-2). This supports HTML display and will close automatically. Tooltips are meant to display volatile information to users, `QLabel` is not.

Comment: I initially tried that - but the desired HTML includes links, which doesn't work in a QToolTip - the tooltip disappears before you can move the mouse to the link.